# Meteor find all user emails

Tags: javascript, email, meteor

I'm trying to gather all user emails on a Meteor server function (to send to all on an event). I have tried many constructions and have got to this:

```
/server/lib/mail/mailNewEvent.js

Meteor.users.find({}, {transform: function(doc) {return doc.profile}}).fetch();
```

which returns:

```
[ { name: 'Tardar',
    email: 'rsartsnie@eintrs.com',
    _id: 'YyEk2sLDiQoBjC6gS' },
  { name: 'Chutney',
    email: 'rstrtsrtsnie@eintrs.com',
    _id: '4Dyaa5wRmxmq7j7XF' } ]
```

I tried to change the above `transform` to return the email field with:

```
return doc.profile.email
```

but: ["Transform functions must return an object"](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection) and that gives a variable.

I have also tried:

```
Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {'profile.email': 1, _id:0}}).fetch();
```

which returns:

```
[ { profile: { email: 'rsartsnie@eintrs.com' } },
  { profile: { email: 'rstrtsrtsnie@eintrs.com' } } ]
```

Can I make this happen with `find`'s own functionality or do I have to act on the array separately?

Comment: The method must return only an array with all the emails? like `['rsartsnie@eintrs.com', 'rstrtsrtsnie@eintrs.com' ]`?

Comment: That would be best yes. The array will be used to populate the email To: field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this :

```
Meteor.users.find({}).map(function(user){
   return user.profile.email
})
```

[Documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/map)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function from underscore.js named `map` ([reference](http://underscorejs.org/#map)):

```
var emails = _.map(Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {'profile.email': 1, _id:0}}).fetch(), function(user) {
    return user.profile.email;
});
```

Or even shorter with `pluck` ([reference](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck)):

```
var emails = _.pluck(Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {'profile.email': 1, _id:0}}).fetch(), 'profile.email');
```

They'll iterate over the result and produce an array with the desired data